# Split into multiple items by splitting at ;

Tags: php, arrays

I have some items in a database like

```
Apple Juice;Orange Juice;Pineapple Juice;Cranberry Juice;Milk;
```

How can i split them so each one is in a PHP array

Comment: are you search on Google how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a really basic [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) that you are looking for:

```
$yourString='Apple Juice;Orange Juice;Pineapple Juice;Cranberry Juice;Milk;';

$yourArray=explode(';',$yourString);

print_r($yourArray);
```

Edit:

To remove empty array fields, we can simply use the [array filter function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like this:

```
$yourString='Apple Juice;Orange Juice;Pineapple Juice;Cranberry Juice;Milk;';

$yourArray=array_filter(explode(';',$yourString));

print_r($yourArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great, However because i have a ; at the end, How can i not make it give a new entry for that last one, as i have a radio button for each entry in the array and i have just a blank radio button with no text next to it.

Comment: @Exoon I made an edit to the answer that uses filter to only populate your array with non empty fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = explode(";", "Apple Juice;Orange Juice;Pineapple Juice;Cranberry Juice;Milk");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$items = explode(";", "Apple Juice;Orange Juice;Pineapple Juice;Cranberry Juice;Milk");

<pre>
print_r($items)
</pre>
```